# How to calculate input mathematical equation in C

Tags: c

Consider three square matrices A, B, and I.

```
A = [1 2 3]        B = [-1 2 3]       I = [1 0 0]
    [1 1 1]            [ 2 8 2]           [0 1 0]
    [1 3 5]            [ 1 1 2]           [0 0 1]
```

Write a program that takes a mathematical expression, which involves “addition” (+) and “subtraction” (-), and evaluate the expression. Note that A, B, and I are fixed. Your program should perform the proper matrix operations (element-wise addition and subtraction).

```
* Example
command: A+A
2   4   6
2   2   2
2   6   10

* Example
command: A-A
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0

* Example
command: A+B+I
1   4   6
3   10  3
2   4   8
```

I was practicing C programming by myself, and I have no idea how to evaluate input mathematical expressions... I know how to add and subtract matrix, but don't know how to start calculating when user input something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3
void addition(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int c[3][3]){
     int sum[3][3], i, j;
     for(i=0; i<N; i++){
       for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j] + c[i][j];
       }
     }

     for(i=0;i<N;i++){
       for(j=0;j<N;j++){
         printf("%d\t",sum[i][j]);
        }
       printf("\n");
      }
}

void subtraction(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int c[3][3]){
     int dif[3][3], i, j;
     for(i=0; i<N; i++){
       for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         dif[i][j] = a[i][j] - b[i][j] - c[i][j];
       }
     }

     for(i=0;i<N;i++){
       for(j=0;j<N;j++){
         printf("%d\t",dif[i][j]);
        }
       printf("\n");
      }
}

int main(){
  int A[N][N]={{1,2,3}, {1,1,1}, {1,3,5}};
  int B[N][N]={{-1,2,3}, {2,8,2}, {1,1,2}};
  int I[N][N]={{1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1}};

  char command[30];
  printf("command: ");
  scanf("%s",command);



  addition(A, B, I);

  return 0;
}
```

I think I messed up from beginning
Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one function that analyses the `command`. This function will split your command by the letter-word and the operators (addition or subtraction). After splitting the command, you can use the `switch ... case` to choose the *variables* and *operators* from the command.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your add/subtract functions to be binary operations (i.e. they should take two rather than three arguments):

```
void addMatrix(int left[N][N], int right[N][N], int result[N][N] ) ;
void subMatrix(int left[N][N], int right[N][N], int result[N][N] ) ;
```

The "display" of results should be separated, that is not part of the add/subtract operation, and you don't in any case want to print intermediate results. A separate `printMatrix( int mat[N][N] ) ;` would be appropriate

The input needs to be parsed such that the *characters* `'A'`, `'B'` and `'I'` map to the matrices `A`, `B` and `I`, and the characters `'+'` and `'-'` map to the functions `addMatrix()` and `subMatrix()' respectively. Such that for example "A + B - I" results in a call sequence:

```
addMatrix( A, B, result ) ;
subMatrix( result, I, result ) ;
printMatrix( result ) ;
```

Note that in the second call the left-hand operand is also the output container - the operator functions will need a temporary matrix to build the result, then copy that back to the result before returning.

The following is an example expression parser - treat this as a pseudo-code "hint" at a solution - I have not tested, or even compiled it.

```
int main()
{
    const int A[N][N] = {{1,2,3}, {1,1,1}, {1,3,5}};
    const int B[N][N] = {{-1,2,3}, {2,8,2}, {1,1,2}};
    const int I[N][N] = {{1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1}};


    printf( "command: " );
    fflush( stdout ) ;

    int** left = 0 ;
    int** right = 0 ;
    void (*op)(int**, int**, int**) ;
    int result[N][N] = {0};
    char ch ;

    do
    {
        ch = getchar() ;

        switch( ch )
        {
            case 'A': if( left == 0 ) left = A ; else right = A ;
            break ;

            case 'B': if( left == 0 ) left = B ; else right = B ;
            break ;

            case 'I': if( left == 0 ) left = I ; else right = I ;
            break ;

            case '+': op = addMatrix ;
            break ;

            case '-': op = subMatrix ;
            break ;
        }

        // If there is a complete sub-expression...
        if( op != 0 && left != 0; right != 0 )
        {
            // Perform the operation
            op( left, right, result ) ;

            // result becomes left operand for next operation
            left = result ;
        }

    } while( ch != '\n' ) ;

    printMatrix( result ) ;
}
```